# What cookie request is a suspect request?

Tags: php, cookies, mysql

I have this table which is containing all users' cookies: *(about being login. that's actually "remember me checked")*

```
// cookies
+----+---------+-------------------+------------+
| id | user_id |       token       |   expire   |
+----+---------+-------------------+------------+
| 1  | 32423   | dki3j4rf9u3e40... | 1467586386 |
| 2  | 65734   | erhj5473fv34gv... | 1467586521 |
| 3  | 21432   | 8u34ijf34t43gf... | 1467586640 |
+----+---------+-------------------+------------+
```

And I check both `user_id` and `token` columns to validate an cookie:

```
SELECT 1
FROM cookies
WHERE user_id = :id AND
      token   = :token
```

Well there is 5 cases:

1. row exists
2. row doesn't exist because `user_id = :id` is *false*
3. row doesn't exist because `token = :token` is *false*
4. row doesn't exist because both `user_id = :id` and `token = :token` are *false*
5. row doesn't exist because `user_id = :id` and `token = :token` are *true* but not in the same row.

**My Question:** Which case is dangerous and I have to care about it? Which one isn't important and I have to ignore it?

---

Ok well, what about this theory? *"No need to check `user_id` column at all:"*

```
SELECT 1
FROM cookies
WHERE token = :token
```

So there is just two cases:

1. row exists
2. row doesn't exist because `token = :token` is *false*

And then nothing there is suspicious. So is this theory good *(secure)*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ensure your token contains enough entropy (> 128 bits), then you shouldn't need to check user ID as well.

I would also store the token hashed within your database using something at least as secure as SHA-2, that way if your remember-me table is compromised in any way, an attacker can't hijack sessions. The cookie set on the client should be the raw value. Note that salt is not needed for sufficiently strong random values.

Comment: Good point about hashing before putting into DB

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have chosen a sufficiently large CSPRNG for the token, checking it should be sufficient. Somewhere in the 128 to 256 bit size should be sufficient.

You don't mention where you're storing the token in the user's browser. Cookies are typically used for this. You should have the *Secure* and *HttpOnly* setting on the cookie. Basically, you should take security precautions similar to [security for a session cookie](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Management_Cheat_Sheet).

As far as not finding a matching row in the database, that is not necessarily a problem. For example, a row could be missing because your site deleted it due to it being very old. The security concern would be if someone is trying to search through the tokens to find a valid one. You can just rely on probability to make this impossible by making sure you choose sufficiently long and random tokens.